# Superset passing time filter from dashboard to custom query

Tags: filter, dashboard, apache-superset

In one slice, Custom query is needed to union 2 dataset from different filter.
Each dataset has its date/time filer. How could Superset know that which datename to be used for which query.

The example of custom query below.

```
1 SELECT "PRE" AS "Stage","Tutorial Flight"."Travel Date" AS "Travel_Date",
2       "Tutorial Flight"."Airline" AS "Airline",
3       sum("Cost") AS "Cost"
4 FROM  "Tutorial Flight"
5 WHERE 
6 "Travel Date" = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000','{{ from_dttm.isoformat() }}')
7 AND  "Tutorial Flight"."Airline"  in ( {{ "'" + "','".join(filter_values('Airline')) + "'" }} )
8 GROUP BY 
9        "Travel Date", "Airline"
10 UNION
11 SELECT "POST" AS "Stage","Tutorial Flight"."Travel Date" AS "Travel_Date",
12       "Tutorial Flight"."Airline" AS "Airline",
13       sum("Cost") AS "Cost"
14 FROM "Tutorial Flight"
15 WHERE 
16 "Travel Date" = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000','{{ from_dttm.isoformat() }}')
17 AND  "Tutorial Flight"."Airline"  in ( {{ "'" + "','".join(filter_values('Airline')) + "'" }} )
18 GROUP BY "Travel Date", "Airline"
```

There are 3 filters used in this case.
date_time for Pre date
date_time for Post date  and
Airline which apply to both query.

how could we define in from_dttm.isoformat() to use correct datetime from the table if

1. date filter coming from the same table
2. date filter coming from different table.

I have tried but it always use from one table only.
Here is the json from one time filter

```
{"cache_key": null, "cached_dttm": null, "cache_timeout": 86400, "error": null, "form_data": {"datasource": "18__table", "viz_type": "filter_box", "slice_id": 295, "url_params": {}, "granularity_sqla": "Travel Date", "time_range": "2020-06-15T00:00:00 : 2020-06-15T00:00:00", "filter_configs": [], "date_filter": true, "instant_filtering": true, "show_sqla_time_granularity": false, "show_sqla_time_column": false, "show_druid_time_granularity": false, "show_druid_time_origin": false, "adhoc_filters": [], "where": "", "having": "", "having_filters": [], "filters": []}, "is_cached": false, "query": "", "status": null, "stacktrace": null, "rowcount": 0, "data": {}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `{{from_dttm}}` and `{{to_dttm}}`